# iOS Button position x,y 3,5 inch to 4 inch

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios-autolayout

I'm trying to do an auto-layout of my screen of 3.5 inches to 4, but the “PEDIR” button is too large or is glued in label or in bottom. I need that button to be on center of the space left from the label "SEU PEDIDO..." to bottom. What is the best way to do that?

> 3,5 inch:

[image: 3,5 inch]

> 4 inch:

[image: 4 inch]

**Edit**

Now I'm getting this warning:

[image: warning]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

1. Create a container view for your button then pin it to all sides:

   [image]
2. Create constraints for your button(Gold) be centered vertically in its superview(Gray). `Don't forget to add width and height constraint`.

   [image]
3. Here is the output on 4-inch:

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

[image: Make the bottom space Fixed (3 is just an example)]

Make the bottom space Fixed (3 is just an example) in your case it should be around 40.
Take a look at this example from apple doc.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-interface_builder/articles-autolayout/pin-constraints.html

Comment: Tried to do that, it worked. But not in 3,5 inch. I've edited my question with the picture of the warning.